# UICollectionView with sticky footer in iphone X, content scrolled to area below footer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, iphone-x

In my `UICollectionView`, I made the following settings:

```
let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
flowLayout.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds = true
flowLayout.sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea
```

However, on `iPhoneX`, the `collectionView` content will `scroll` to area under the sticky `footer` as shown in [collection View in iphone X with sticky footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d5hg.png)

Can anyone give any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Check the bottom constraint of collection view it should be from your bottom bar not from safe area.

Answer (score -3):

Set scroll view content insets to Never

[image: Collection View Size Inspector]